# Why does Swift use base 2 for the exponent of hexadecimal floating point values?

Tags: floating-point, swift

According to *The Swift Programming Language* :

> For example, 0xFp2 represents 15 ⨉ 2^2, which evaluates to 60.
>   Similarly, 0xFp-2 represents 15 ⨉ 2^(-2), which evaluates to 3.75.

Why is 2 used as base for the exponent instead of 16? I'd have expected `0xFp2 == 15 * (16**2)` instead of `0xFp2 == 15 * (2**2)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swift's hexadecimal notation for floating-point numbers is just a variation of the [notation introduced for C in the C99 standard](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/) for both input and output (with the printf `%a` format).

The purpose of that notation is to be both easy to interpret by humans and to let the bits of the [IEEE 754 representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) be somewhat recognizable. The IEEE 754 representation uses base two. Consequently, for a normal floating-point number, when the number before `p` is between `1` and `2`, the number after `p` is directly the value of the exponent field of the IEEE 754 representation. This is in line with the dual objectives of human-readability and closeness to the bit representation:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("%a\n", 3.14);
}
$ gcc t.c && ./a.out 
0x1.91eb851eb851fp+1
```

The number `0x1.91eb851eb851fp+1` can be seen to be slightly above 3 because the exponent is `1` and the significand is near `0x1.9`, slightly above `0x1.8`, which indicates the exact middle between two powers of two.

This format helps remember that numbers that have a compact representation in decimal are not necessarily simple in binary. In the example above, `3.14` uses all the digits of the significand to approximate (and even so, it isn't represented exactly).

Hexadecimal is used for the number before the `p`, which corresponds to the significand in the IEEE 754 format, because it is more compact than binary. The significand of an IEEE 754 binary64 number requires 13 hexadecimal digits after `0x1.` to represent fully, which is a lot, but in binary 52 digits would be required, which is frankly impractical.

The choice of hexadecimal actually has its drawbacks: because of this choice, the several equivalent representations for the same number are not always easy to recognize as equivalent. For instance, `0x1.3p1` and `0x2.6p0` represent the same number, although their digits have nothing in common. In binary, the two notations would correspond to `0b1.0011p1` and `0b10.011p0`, which would be easier to see as equivalent. To take another example, `3.14` can also be represented as `0xc.8f5c28f5c28f8p-2`, which is extremely difficult to see as the same number as `0x1.91eb851eb851fp+1`. This problem would not exist if the number after the `p` represented a power of 16, as you suggest in your question, but unicity of the representation was not an objective when C99 was standardized: closeness to the IEEE 754 representation was.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that every floating-point number of any particular type would have a unique canonical representation in that form, if one were to specify particular representations for +/- zero, and otherwise required that the leading digit be a `1` and that the number of digits specified be sufficient to "fill out" the type?

Comment: @supercat Compiler output is in practice normalized in a fashion similar to this (on my compilation platform, except for 80-bit `long double`; this is how I obtained the alternative form for 3.14). Allowing all variants in the input direction has its advantages, for instance for integers (0x7fffffff.0p0) and for table entries (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23726810/139746 )

Comment: It's certainly useful for a compiler to accept non-canonical representations, especially in situations where many values are fractions of the form m/2^p *for the same p*.  The output of sin(x) has a constant *meaningful* dynamic range which extends from 0 to 1, even when x is near pi; showing the values in denormalized form makes their relative significance much clearer than showing them in normalized form.