# Swift: Numeric Literals Decimal Floats Exponents

Tags: swift, math

I have a question about exponents in  for decimal float exponents.

**Decimal**

```
 let decimalTest = 2e3
```

which is

```
2 * 10^3 = 2000
```

**Hexadecimal**

```
let hexaTest = 0x2p3
```

which is

```
2 * 2^3 = 16
```

Why would the hexadecimal be multiplied by an exponent with a base of 2 instead of 16?

edit: formatting & forgot to declare hexadecimal for the hexaTest

Comment: You might want to look at the following SO question since this question has been asked before and very thoroughly answered :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477546/why-does-swift-use-base-2-for-the-exponent-of-hexadecimal-floating-point-values

Comment: Thanks for the comment!